# Set/edit SoundCloud users' description via the API

Tags: soundcloud

Is there a way to set the description of a SoundCloud user via the API? We have an app for musician "dates" and would like to automatically add dates to users' profiles.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Javascript, after you have authenticated your user, you can change a user's description with this function:

```
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'your_client_id',
  redirect_uri: 'your_callback_url'
});

SC.connect().then(function() {
   SC.put('/me', {
     user: { description: 'the new description' }
   });
});
</script>
```

If you are using Php, provided that you are using Soundcloud's docs, you can do that like this:

```
    user = client.post('/me', :description => 'I am using the SoundCloud API!')
puts user.description
```

For more info, you can go here:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication. Scroll down to the '**Getting Information about the Authenticated User**' section

Hope I helped